# Implementing SSL in Java Based Web Applications

Tags: mysql, security, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a java based web application developed in Amazon EC2. It is doing transactions of confidential information. I have a MySQL server installed all by my self in the same amazon instance. The web application access the database via `localhost`. In `Security Groups`, I have created a custom security where the port `8080` (the `Tomcat`) can be accessed only via `localhost`.

Considering these, do I still need SSL to make sure the transactions are secured?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Are you comfortable with plain text inside the datacenter? Don't bother with SSL.

Are you worried about that traffic being sniffed locally (tcpdump) or from a malicious source ([for instance, if data was being rerouted from the switch between EC2 instances](http://www.zdnet.com/article/prism-heres-how-the-nsa-wiretapped-the-internet/))? Use SSL.

[There's a trend of large companies making sure to encrypt local traffic.](http://techcrunch.com/2013/11/18/yahoo-will-follow-google-in-encrypting-data-center-traffic-all-traffic-between-company-and-customers-by-q1-14/)